# Specify which column not to load or load a range of columns in numpy.loadtxt()

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I have a folder containing 10 similar text files. I'm using numpy.loadtxt() to open a text file. I extract a specific row and rest columns except first 4 columns. Then I apply same action to all text files then concatenate these data. But the length of  the specific row for different text files is unknown and different.

As a reference for one text file the specific row is:

```
Mean CD (nm) =  19.319  19.306  19.268  19.239  19.309  19.313  19.296....
```

The following is my code:

```
path = "/data/All Images"
filePaths = [os.path.join(path,filename) 
             for filename in listdir(path) 
             if re.match(r"^.*tif_batch.*\.txt$", filename)]  

CD = np.concatenate([np.loadtxt(f, dtype = str, skiprows = 54, max_rows = 1, usecols = range(4, ), unpack=False) for f in filePaths]) #concatenate data from all files processed in same way(skip 54 rows)
```

The actual result is:

```
['Mean' 'CD' '(nm)' '=' 'Mean' 'CD' '(nm)' '=' 'Mean' 'CD' '(nm)' '='
 'Mean' 'CD' '(nm)' '=' 'Mean' 'CD' '(nm)' '=' 'Mean' 'CD' '(nm)' '='
 'Mean' 'CD' '(nm)' '=' 'Mean' 'CD' '(nm)' '=' 'Mean' 'CD' '(nm)' '=']
```

The expected result is:

```
 ['15.583' '15.516' '15.563' '15.550' '15.510' --from text 1
  '15.569' '15.518' '15.532' '15.560' '15.545' --from text 2
.................................]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to strip the first 4 columns and it works.

```
    path = "/data/All Images"
    filePaths = [os.path.join(path,filename) 
                 for filename in listdir(path) 
                 if re.match(r"^.*tif_batch.*\.txt$", filename)]  

    CD_0 = np.concatenate([np.loadtxt(f, dtype = str, skiprows = 54, max_rows = 1, unpack=False) for f in filePaths]) #concatenate data from all files processed in same way(skip 54 rows) #load the whole row
    strip = np.array(['Mean', 'CD', '(nm)', '=']) #set element you don't need
    CD = np.setdiff1d(CD_0, b, assume_unique = True) #strip element from CD_0
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this line:

```
np.loadtxt(..., usecols = range(4, ), ...)
```

Let's see what `range(4, )` is equal to:

```
>>> list(range(4))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

So, you're retrieving *the first 4 columns*.

I can see where this is coming from: maybe the `some_list[4:]` syntax made you think `range(4, )` would create a kind of range from 4 to infinity, but it doesn't:

```
>>> help(range)
Help on built-in function range in module __builtin__:

range(...)
    range(stop) -> list of integers  # THIS IS WHAT YOUR CODE IS USING
    range(start, stop[, step]) -> list of integers
```

You should extract all the columns from the 4th to the 10th one, both ends included:

```
>>> list(range(4, 10 + 1))
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Ya. I know how range( ) works. And the data is a reference. The problem is that there are unknown number of columns for different rows and different text files. So I am wandering how I can get specific range of columns or not load the first 4 columns.